# angular2-google-maps@0.17.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.1 but none was installed

Tags: angular, angular2-google-maps

I am getting this error in my application.

> angular2-google-maps@0.17.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.1
>   but none was installed.

How can I solve it?

Comment: add package.json to the question

Comment: I already added package json

Comment: {
  "name": "automaps",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },

Comment: @Charan, what does the following output if run inside the project `$ npm list --depth=0 | grep common`?

Comment: @maximus npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.3.1, required by angular2-google-m
aps@0.17.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.1, required by angular2-google-map
s@0.17.0

Comment: well, what this error says is that you don't have @angular/common@2.3.1 and `@angular/core@^2.3.1` installed. What versions of these do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/common@^2.3.1` means `>=2.3.1 <3.0.0`.

- If you are on angular <2.3.1 just update to 2.4 or 4.1.
- If you are on angular 4, just ignore this message, since it's backwards compatible with Angular 2.

Btw after 0.17.0 or higher, angular2-google-maps has been changed to @ngui/map.

```
npm install @ngui/map @types/googlemaps --save
```

See the [usage instructions](https://github.com/ng2-ui/map#usage)